# Securing REST API in PHP

Tags: php, api, jwt, basic-authentication

All my database related files are in config folder (fetch, post, update, delete). and I'm using ajax on the client side to use that data. my question is how can I secure my API files. I've studded about JWT and I think it is only for user login and signup. I want that when someone opens my api url like: 'http://localhost/config/getPosts.php' they should be authenticated before they can see the posts. I've also used basic auth but it is not secure according to my research.

Comment: `I've studded about JWT and I think it is only for user login and signup`...then think again. The purpose of having someone sign up to your API is so that they can login and authenticate when they want to access one of the resources. The JWT token is what they provide to your URLs after they have obtained it by authenticating with the login URL.

Comment: so Should I be using JWT technique. I just want no body to be able to see what I have there. I just want to use it from the ajax call within my app.

Comment: `Should I be using JWT technique`... there's no "should" about it. It's one authentication method you _could_ use, yes. There are others potentially, depending on your exact requirements. If you're unsure, do some research into authentication schemes commonly used to protect APIs

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to create a way to check if the user is currently logged in with JWT (Usually done with a middleware) and if not return a 401 error. Then assign the middleware to those routes so you protect those routes with the JWT check.